# how to get the maximum fps in ipad?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, ipad

I have developed a game for iPhone using coco2d 0.99.3. I want it to work on iPad. I have the new images which are bigger in size and resolution than iPhone images.

Every thing is fine, but I got the fps problem. In iphone simulator I used to get 50 - 60 fps and even in iPhone device I used to get 50 above fps.

But, in ipad simulator the fps is very low, it is below 10fps. I could not understand where is the problem. What should I do to raise the fps ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

this is a common phenomenon among other developers (including myself)

BUT it's nothing to worry about; fps on the real iPad are much higher than the simulator.  However, this only seems to happen with large images, so I don't add them till the very end of the development process.  You can get reasonable results by doing so.

hope this helps